# Lemma 2.1. Lee's Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

From the book [Riemannian Manifolds - Lee](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/Riemannian_Manifolds/92PgBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=lee%20riemannian%20geometry&printsec=frontcover), specifically in the chapter about tensors.

First the definition of a tensor type $\begin{pmatrix} k \\ l\end{pmatrix}$ is given as a multilinear map
$$
F : \underbrace{V^* \times \dots \times V^*}_{l \text{ copies}} \times \underbrace{V \times \dots \times V}_{k \text{ copies}} \to \mathbb{R}
$$

The set of such tensors is denoted by $T_l^k(V)$. The space $T_1^1(V)$ can be identified with $\text{End}(V)$. And such identification is generalized by the following lemma

> **Lemma 2.1.**: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. There is a natural (basis-independent) isomorphism between $T_{l+1}^k(V)$ and the space of multilinear maps
> $$
> F : \underbrace{V^* \times \dots \times V^*}_{l} \times \underbrace{V \times \dots \times V}_{k} \to V
> $$

And it is given as exercise to prove the lemma, which is what I am trying to do. A hint is given

> **Hint** In the special case $k = 1, l = 0$ consider the map $\Phi : \text{End}(V) \to T_1^1(V)$ by letting $\Phi A$ be the $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ tensor defined by $\Phi A (\omega, X) = \omega(AX)$.

Maybe this is very simple but I get confused.
To prove $\Phi$ is linear let's take $A, B \in \text{End}(V)$ and $\alpha,\beta$ scalars then
$$
\Phi(\alpha A + \beta B)(\omega,X) = \omega((\alpha A + \beta B)X) = \omega(\alpha A X+ \beta B X) = \omega(\alpha A X) + \omega(\beta B X) = \alpha \omega(A X) + \beta \omega(B X) = \alpha \Phi A(\omega,X) + \beta \Phi B(\omega,X) = \left( \alpha \Phi A + \beta \Phi B \right)(\omega,X)
$$
and this yields
$$
\Phi(\alpha A + \beta B) = \alpha \Phi A + \beta \Phi B
$$
hence linearity. To prove $\Phi$ is an isomorphism I can use the dimension theorem
$$
\text{dim End}(V) = \text{dim Ker}{\Phi} + \text{dim Range}{\Phi}
$$

therefore if I show that $\text{Ker}(\Phi) = \left\{ 0 \right\}$ I am done. I think this is easy up to a step. Suppose $\Phi A = \Phi B$ then we have for every $\omega \in V^*, X \in V$

$$
\Phi A(\omega,X) = \Phi B(\omega,X) \Rightarrow 0 = \Phi A(\omega,X) - \Phi B(\omega, X) = \omega(AX) - \omega(BX) = \omega( (A - B) X) \Rightarrow \omega ( (A - B) X ) = 0.
$$

since this hold for every $\omega, X$ then we must have $A - B = 0$ and hence $A = B$. So $\Phi$ is injective and specifically $dim \text{Ker}(\Phi) = 0$ and hence $\text{dim End}(V) =\text{dim Range}{\Phi}$ and therefore we have the map is an isomorphism.

**Question**: Correct so far?

To fully prove the Lemma however I think I need another hint. But I assume I need to redefine $\Phi$ somewhat.

Comment: Hint: For example in the case $k=2,l=0$ you can consider $F$ as a linear map $V \to \mathrm{End}(V)$ and then you can use what you have shown.

Comment: You do need to redefine $\Phi$, but in an analogous way. Once you do that, the argument is the same. Given a map $F : V \times V \to V$ for example, do you have any guesses on how to define $\Phi F \in T^2_1(V)$?

Comment: Btw I think it’s more efficient to just write down an inverse for $\Phi$ (you’ll need to invoke the fact that $V\cong V^{**}$).